# Mysql select complex query

Tags: php, mysql

I am sorry for the vague title but I really cannot make this any more specific with my English.

I have this table called `posts__tags` that I use to associate `post ids` and `tag ids` with the following columns

`record_id`, `post_id` and `tag_id`. Here is an example sample

```
record_id | post_id | tag_id  
1         |    1    |   1     
2         |    1    |   2     
3         |    1    |   3     
4         |    2    |   2     
5         |    3    |   1     
6         |    3    |   3     
7         |    4    |   2     
8         |    4    |   3     
9         |    4    |   4
```

I have a php function that has an array of `tag_ids` as a parameter. Lets say for example that my parameter is the `array(2,3)`. I need to select all the post_id's that are associated with `tag_id = 2` AND `tag_id = 3`.

In the above example I should get the 1 and 4 post_id's since only those are associated with both 2 and 3 tag_id 's.

What is the best way to achieve that with a MySQL query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that record is apparently redundant. A perfectly serviceable PK can be formed on the remaining columns.

Comment: record_id is used in different queries, just not in this one but thanks for the point!

Comment: Are you sure? That seems a little unlikely

Comment: I m pretty sure yeps, I am trying to fix some functions of an already working site without changing too much in the database structure and the database is not ideally designed, so yes the record_id is used in other queries although those wueries could be used differently.

Comment: Well make sure that a composite index exists on the remaining columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select post_id from posts__tags where tag_id in (1,2) group by post_id having count(*)=2
```

Comment: Thanks it works, just a question though, I assume count(*) = X where X is the length of the tag_ids array right?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
select distinct post_id from table_name where tag_id in (2,3)
```

Comment: For some reason it returns all records that have post_id associated with tag_id=2 OR tag_id=3. I need the ones that are associated with BOTH those ids.

Comment: send me your sql query

Comment: Group by post_id having count(*) = 2 [no distincts required here]

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM posts__tags WHERE tag_id IN (".implode(",", $tag_ids).") where $tag_ids is the array(2,3)

Comment: Strawberry thanks for your reply, can you post the query? I m a bit of a novice so the full query would help!